# Return an empty list/output when scrape a dynamic website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a dynamic website, the link is below.
https://publicrecordsaccess.fultoncountyga.gov/Portal/Home/WorkspaceMode?p=0

If the link needs you to search again, here is what I put for the Search Criteria: 16ED* then click Advanced Filtering Options to choose the Filter by File Date Start: 01/01/2016 and Filter by File Date End: 01/08/2016. Then click submit. You will go to the webpage that I need to scrape from.

My goal is to scrape the website from Case Number, Style/Defendant, File Date, Type, Status, and the corresponding URL for the Case. Then store them into a dataframe. I can see all the information when I click Inspect on Google Chrome. And since I know it is a dynamic website, I wrote code that uses Selenium to scrape the website.

```
web = 'https://publicrecordsaccess.fultoncountyga.gov/Portal/Home/WorkspaceMode?p=0'

op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
op.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
driver.get(web)
time.sleep(10)
plain_text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

# Records = soup.find_all("tr", {"class":"k-master-row"})
```

But for some reason, there's nothing in the soup when I run the code above, I am wondering did I do something wrong and how should I fix it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm not familiar with beautifulsoup, but maybe you should work in normal, not headless mode?

Comment: `page_source` gets you the original page text, exactly if you had used `requests`.  If this is a dynamic web site, then you need to use the APIs to search through the DOM to find the entries you need.

Comment: @Prophet I tried not use headless mode but still giving me an empty output

Comment: @TimRoberts what kind of APIs or libraries should I be using if I want to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  You'll need to use the Developer Tools to figure out how to find the elements you need, then use FindElement or FindElements to extract those elements.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I used the Developer Tools to inspect the source and I can see the information that I need but I don't know how to scrape it using Python

Comment: Then you need to go read about Selenium.  It's a complicated topic, and there are many, many tutorials.  We can't teach you web scraping in a few short comments.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think I figure out the reason why. The selenium Chrome web driver is throwing me an HTTP Error 503 when tried to load the URL. But when I opened that website in normal Google Chrome, it works fine.